# How to query an embedded database stored in hdfs from a Mapreduce job?

Tags: java, hadoop, geolocation, hdfs

I am trying to query the GeoLite Database from Hadoop MapReduce mapper to resolve country of an IP address. I tried two approaches:

1.Using `File` only works in local file system and I receive a file not found exception

```
File database = new File("hdfs://localhost:9000/input/GeoLite2-City.mmdb"); // <<< HERE
DatabaseReader reader = new DatabaseReader.Builder(database).build();
```

2.Using streams, but I get this error during runtime

> Error: Java Heap Space

```
Path pt = new Path("hdfs://localhost:9000/input/GeoLite2-City.mmdb");
FileSystem fs = FileSystem.get(new Configuration());

FSDataInputStream stream = fs.open(pt);
DatabaseReader reader = new DatabaseReader.Builder(stream).build();

InetAddress ipAddress = InetAddress.getByName(address.getHostAddress());
CityResponse response = null;
try {
    response = reader.city(ipAddress);
} catch (GeoIp2Exception ex) {
    ex.printStackTrace();
    return;
}
```

My question: is how to query geolite database from mapper in Hadoop?

Comment: `Error: Java Heap Space` so why don't you give the mapper more heap space?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### I solved it by the distributed Cache method, by caching the GeoLite Database file to every mapper in the MapReduce job.

```
    @Override
      public void setup(Context context)
    
      {
        Configuration conf = context.getConfiguration();
    
        try {
    
          cachefiles = DistributedCache.getLocalCacheFiles(conf);
    
          File database = new File(cachefiles[0].toString()); //
    
          reader = new DatabaseReader.Builder(database).build();
    
        } catch (IOException e) {
          e.printStackTrace();
        }
    
      }
public void map(Object key, Text line, Context context) throws IOException,
      InterruptedException {

                     .....

InetAddress ipAddress = InetAddress.getByName(address.getHostAddress());
      CityResponse response = null;
      try {
        response = reader.city(ipAddress);
      } catch (GeoIp2Exception ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
        return;
      }
                     ......
```